# Is there a category theoretic definition of the naturals as an analogue to the set theoretic definition?

Tags: category-theory, foundations

And similarly, is there a category theoretic construction of the real numbers?

Comment: There's more than one set-theoretic definition of the real numbers.

Comment: K. My question still stands.

Comment: The reals are the terminal object in the category of Archimedean ordered fields.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the [variety of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) consisting of sets with a single 0-ary operation (otherwise thought of as a constant element) $i$, a single unary operation $S$, and no identities.  Then $(\mathbb{N}, i := 0, S := (n \mapsto n + 1))$ is an initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ (and therefore every initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ is uniquely isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ with these operations).  This essentially gives $\mathbb{N}$ in a way very similar to the operations in the language of Peano arithmetic.

For other characterizations, $(\mathbb{N}, 0, +)$ is also the free monoid on one generator; and $(\mathbb{N}, 0, 1, +, \cdot)$ is the initial semiring.